# Create new velocity column from distance and datetime data

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a downward velocity model for offshore drilling which uses the variables Depth (which increases every 1 foot) and DateTime data which is more intermittent and is only updated every foot of depth:

```
Dept      DateTime
1141      5/24/2017 04:31
1142      5/24/2017 04:32
1143      5/24/2017 04:40
1144      5/24/2017 04:42
1145      5/25/2017 04:58
```

I am trying to get something like this:
[image]

Where Velocity iterated down dept/(DateTime gap)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data - copy and paste them as text then format them as code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting ... https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.  
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755).

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, this is straightforward with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

# read file into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

# convert series to datetime
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

# perform calculation
df['Velocity'] = df['Dept'].diff() / (df['DateTime'].diff().dt.total_seconds() / 60)

# expert to csv
df.to_csv('file_out.csv', index=False)

print(df)
#    Dept            DateTime  Velocity
# 0  1141 2017-05-24 04:31:00       NaN
# 1  1142 2017-05-24 04:32:00  1.000000
# 2  1143 2017-05-24 04:40:00  0.125000
# 3  1144 2017-05-24 04:42:00  0.500000
# 4  1145 2017-05-25 04:58:00  0.000687
```